# How to Convert TRUE/FALSE to Checkboxes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to Convert TRUE/FALSE to Checkboxes in Google Sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Just note that blank cells will convert to unchecked checkbox if included in the range. This should work on the sample sheet you provided. This will not convert anything to checkbox if the cells are not containing blank, true or false.

```
function generateCheckBox() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = sheet.getRange('A2:B' + lastRow);

  var validateCheckBox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  validateCheckBox.requireCheckbox();
  validateCheckBox.setAllowInvalid(false);
  validateCheckBox.build();

  column.setDataValidation(validateCheckBox);
}
```

If you have any questions/clarification, feel free to comment below.

Answer (score 1):

As a no code solution you can simply highlight the range that has 'true' and 'false' in it and go to 'insert' on the toolbar and hit 'checkbox'.  This will add the checkboxes in that range while honoring the true and false values as indicated.

Comment: This is no longer working for me. When I do 'inser checkbox', all the selected field have a blank checkbox, regardless of the boolean value ('TRUE'/'FALSE') Any other suggestion/workaround?

Comment: Found the reason: the cell formatting was set to 'Plain text' instead of 'Automatic'. Now it works. (For anyone facing similar issue)